# How can I diagnose a strange build error?

Tags: c#, debugging, build

When I try and build my solution, the project **Utility** doesn't build, with the error  *The type or namespace name 'Devices' could not be found* on the following line, yet the project SensorBoards that defines the `Devices.SensorBoards` namespace builds without error.

```
using Devices.SensorBoards;
```

I may be having a lapse here, but what can I do to help diagnose this error?

BTW, the original project builds, but I have tried to isolate a certain group of classes out of the main solution which is 60 projects big and a bit challenging to reverse engineer.

**DUH!**  Silly me, I copied the projects over from the original project one by one, and then added them to the solution, but I didn't update the project references in the projects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude you may have to open you csproj and check if your reference projects and dll reference are correct,some paths may be screwed up...

Answer (score 1):

That suggests you don't have a reference from Utility to SensorBoards.

Chances are that the build error actually gives a hint - it should have:

> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

in it. Given that this *is* a using directive that's causing the problem, that strongly suggests you should look at your assembly references :)

EDIT: Alternatively, perhaps there aren't any public classes within the Devices.SensorBoards namespace?

Comment: @abmv, @jon, thanks, see my edit for the real problem.  I was just being a bit slow today.